# OneDrive permissions - get full data using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

When setting the permission / access link in OneDrive, there is quite a few options:

[image]

But when accessing the file permission using Microsoft Graph API

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/drive/items/{item_id}/permissions
```

I do not get the `set expiration date`, `set password` or `block download`:
the response looks like this:

```
        {
            "id": "permission_id",
            "roles": [
                "write"
            ],
            "link": {
                "scope": "anonymous",
                "type": "edit",
                "webUrl": "webUrl"
            }
        }
```

How can I get all the data? Should I use a different API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `beta` version of Graph API supports this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{user_id}/drive/items/{item_id}/permissions/{permission_id}
```

will give the following response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('user_id')/drive/items('item_id')/permissions/$entity",
    "expirationDateTime": "2020-04-26T21:00:00Z",
    "hasPassword": true,
    "id": "permission_id",
    "roles": [
        "read"
    ],
    "link": {
        "preventsDownload": true,
        "scope": "anonymous",
        "type": "view",
        "webUrl": "webUrl"
    }
}
```